# what is the difference between scan(n=3) and scan(nmax=3) in R programming

Tags: r, data-science

good day, this might seem like a primitive question. I just started learning R, and I am bothered as I can not tell the difference between these two. thanks

Comment: If you check the code `if (!missing(n)) {
        if (missing(nmax)) 
            nmax <- n/pmax(length(what), 1L)
        else stop("either specify 'nmax' or 'n', but not both.")`  You cannot specify both arguments - only one at a time